# Help structuring MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a transaction table that registers email reads using a tracking pixel in our email marketing messages. I'm trying to structure a query that will give me the records in the transaction table whose last recorded email read was more than 6 weeks ago. Reason being, those transactions haven't "engaged" in our email marketing and I need to update one of their subscriber fields to reflect that (so they can receive a different type of email).

If I were to write it out in English, the statement would look kind of like this:

> Select the row from transactions where the subscriber id IS present more than 6 weeks ago but IS NOT present in the last 6 weeks.

So, one initial thought is to create my recordset of those who have opened emails in the last 6 weeks, then compare that against the rest of the table? Can I do this in one statement or should I break it into two?

Thanks in advance for anybody who can help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SubscriberId
    FROM TransactionTable
    GROUP BY SubscriberId
    HAVING MAX(ReadDate) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe; if I have a couple more WHERE conditions where do I put them? (There's one field that actually excludes them from this query regardless, call it `status = "C"`)

Comment: The `WHERE` comes between the `FROM` and the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Awesome. Worked. Got about 120 records all within the right timeframe. Going to compare a sample of them against a recordset inside 6 weeks to see if this is indeed the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: this worked perfectly. Just so I understand the MAX part correctly, it's going to read all the `ReadDate` values in the table but only return those records whose highest value is less than 6 weeks ago?

Answer (score 0):

No need for fancy math. Your requirement boils down to a simple `<` clause: Any user which has no transactions recorded in the last 6 weeks:

```
SELECT userID
FROM transactionstable
WHERE MAX(timestampfield) < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
GROUP BY userID
```

Comment: But this could still return customers who also have more recent transactions.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply; however, I see how that will give me all the records prior to the 6-week-mark, but how does the query know whether one of those subscribers was also found inside the 6-week-mark? Because I don't want to update those people...just the ones that are outside the 6-week-mark but not inside.

Comment: Good point. revamped the query a little bit. Mostly the same as Joe's above, but using a WHERE clause instead of HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

Define a field which shows the last 6 weeks activity. I mean an integer 0 or 1. Then:

`SELECT * FROM transtable WHERE activityfield = 0 AND datefield < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK)`

Answer (score 0):

If the database you are working with supports Oracle SQL, then try this:

```
SELECT * from transactions
WHERE subscribed_date < SYSDATE-(6*7);
```